# Does definition of a norm on quotient space need a closed subspace?

Tags: normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

In many textbooks, when defining a norm on quotient space, there is a condition that the corresponding subspace needs to be closed(without any explanation). Is this condition necessary for the definition of a norm on quotient space? How to prove it?

Comment: $\inf \{\|x+y\|: y \in M\}=0$ iff $x \in \overline {M}$. So you don't get a norm unless $M$ is closed.